# The type java.io.File cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.assertj.core.api.Assertions

Tags: spring-boot, dependencies, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-dependency

folder: src/test/java

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
```

Under Replace.NONE, i am having error as follows:

```
The type java.io.File cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.assertj.core.api.Assertions
```

I tried adding the below dependency in pom.xml file

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.21.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

but still not able to resolve this bug. This doesnt affect my project but i want to resolve this issue

what is the correct dependency that needs to be added.